# How to convert array with custom data into Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder?

Tags: laravel

If there is a way to convert array with custom data into Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder with some custom/faker model ?

I have callback class which returned Builder, which is called my wrapper configurations of my app :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

final class CustomPoints
{
    public function index(): Builder
    {

        ...
        // I need to read data from external api
        $response     = Http::get('https://externalapi.com/points');

        // I use temperary table for this
        TempPoint::truncate();
        $tempPoints = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        foreach ($tempPoints as $tempPoint) {
            $point = TempPoint::create([
                'name'        => $tempPoint->title,
                ...
            ]);
        }

        $points = TempPoint::offset(($page - 1) * $defaultCount)->limit($first);
        // Builder object is returned
        return $points;
    }
```

I would like to avoid using of TempPoint table but to return Builder with collection of Point models...
How can I do it?

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you are trying to do. As it stands right now, "converting an array into a Builder object with a custom/faker model" does not make any sense.

Comment: Something like this https://hofmannsven.com/2021/faker-provider-in-laravel ?

Comment: I added example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [calebporzio/sushi](https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi) package.

> Eloquent's missing "array" driver.
> Sometimes you want to use Eloquent, but without dealing with a database.